# How to play a sound effect in ajax post way on jQuery and javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to play a sound effect when write a data of post method to mysql server which works with php and receive a xml.

so I wrote a code like following.
When I write a data (#post_send button click), sound works well,
but receive a data, sound doesn't work.

I doubt that sound doesn't work when play sound snippet is in a ajax or similar function..

How to play a sound in ajax post methos?

```
// Start Main code Area //
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Global variable define area
    curr_date = null;
    last_date = "0000-00-00 00:00:00";
    readAjax_timer = null;
    audioElement = null;
    // End of Global variable define area

    audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', './sound/bubble.mp3');

    $("#post_send").click(function () {
        audioElement.play();

        curr_date = getTodayAndTime();
        last_date = curr_date;

        var str_postMsg = $("textarea").val();
        if (str_postMsg == "") {
            return;
        }

        appendShowBubble();
        writeMsgToDB();
    });

    readAjax_timer = setInterval(function() {
        readMsgByAjax();

    }, 2000);

    readMsgByAjax();

});
// End Main code Area //
```

Here is a function of receiving a data.

```
function readMsgByAjax() {
// receive a data from mysql by specified school name with ajax.
    var sch_name = "wonderful_element_school";

    var send_data = "sch_name=" + sch_name +
            "&last_date=" + last_date;

    // call ajax post method
    $.post(
            "PHP_readMsg_sql.php",
            send_data,
            function (data) {

                $(data).find('tr').each(function () {

                    var db_record = $(this); //<= <tr>

                    // if "$(this)" is a table head, continue to next tr.
                    if (db_record.attr("id") == "head") {
                        return;
                    }

                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
                    audioElement.play(); //<== This code doesn't work.
                    //////////////////////////////////////////////////

                    // process contents of tr.
                    var str_message;
                    var str_date;
                    var div_leftframe = $("#left_frame").clone();
                    div_leftframe.css("display", "block");

                    var p_message = div_leftframe.children('p');
                    str_message = db_record.find('td[id=post_message]').text();
                    str_message = str_message.replace(/\u000a/g, "</br>");

                    p_message.html(str_message);

                    var small_message = div_leftframe.children('small');
                    str_date = db_record.find('td[id=post_time]').text();
                    last_date = str_date;

                    str_date = str_date.replace(" ", " at ");

                    small_message.text(str_date);

                    $("#chat_list").append(div_leftframe);
                });
            }
    );


    $("#chat_list").append(div_leftframe);

    var $target = $('html,body');
    $target.animate({scrollTop: $target.height()}, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Put your function declaration inside your document ready scope, otherwise the  sound file variable won't be available to be used (variables defined in functions are only available within that function any any child functions - and the document ready scope is a callback function, so you need your AJAX function to be in that function too to access it)

Comment: I think variables of curr_date, last_date, readAjax_timer and  audioElement are global, isn't it?

Comment: OMG. I had a incorrect knowledge of defining a global variable. :o
@scrowler's answer was correct. :D Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to pass the `audioElement` in the function since it's out of scope of your function as @scrowler mentioned. So you can either add the function in your `document.ready()` scope, or you can change your function to:

```
function readMsgByAjax(audioElement){}
```

And when you call it in your `document.ready()` code, just do this:

```
readMsgByAjax(audioElement);
```